# How does BigQuery handle CPU-intensive queries?

Tags: google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

BigQuery's pricing is based on the amount of data scanned. We would like to use it for queries with a lot of CPU intensive operations e.g. complex RegEx on large XML documents. How does this usage pattern affect pricing? Is my query going to be terminated if it uses too much CPU? Is BigQuery the right choice for us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Billing tier used to be used for such scenarios - price was multiplied by billing tier that in turn was reflection of high compute queries

Since [`November 14 2017`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#november_14_2017) - high compute queries have been phased out. All high compute queries under tier 100 are billed as tier 1. Running a high compute query does not require setting any threshold flag anymore.

All queries above tier 100 will fail with a RESOURCES_EXCEEDED_PER_BYTE error unless the query is running in a reserved instance. Existing users who have run a high compute query higher than tier 100 in the last 30 days (as of Nov 14, 2017) retain the ability to run queries at the higher billing tier until October 31, 2018.

So, your pricing will not be affected  - unless it is too expensive to exceed tier 100 at which point your query fails

Comment: So the only way to know whether the query is going to work is to run it in test mode on a smaller dataset? Do you think this would give us a good amount of certainty as to whether the query is going to work on the full dataset?

Comment: functional testing can definitely be done on smaller dataset, so you know your query works as expected. as of scaling test - I would just do opposite and try to run it with worst case scenario dataset to see if you are exceeding limits or not. also best "tool" in such cases is https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation to see how  exactly your query works so you can guess how it will behave in scale and will be able to optimize it - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices